# Can not remove Anaconda (Mac)

Tags: python, macos

I tried to reinstall the Anaconda on my laptop because there's some issue with geopandas.

But I found that I couldn't remove it with the official procedure.

I tried the code as below:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

And the terminal just said:

```
-bash: conda: command not found
```

I don't know why... It's very frustrating since my Pycharm had an interpreter issue as well.

I cannot find the Pycharm interpreter in Anaconda's bins folder.

Can someone save me?  Thank you!

I'm using mac laptop and the version is 10.14.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to delete Anaconda, and the command conda is not found, that means you succeeded in deleting it.

Comment: But I didn't completely remove all of them. That is my concern...